# Generate random user information Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to generate random user information using Angular 4 and RANDOM USER API. Whenever I try to print the received data to console to check if I got what I wanted I always get 'undefined' message instead of what I wanted to print. I do get an object of a random user with all the parameters that I need, but how can I print and get out the specific parameters from that object. I would really like and appreciate if someone would explain that to me. Thank you in advance.

Here is the Service code I'm using to get the data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserdataService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
  }

  getUserData(){

    return this._http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=name,location,nat,picture')
    .map(res => res.json());

  }

}
```

Here is the Component code where I get the data and try to print it in the console:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserdataService } from '../../services/userdata.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-controller',
  templateUrl: './controller.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./controller.component.css']
})
export class ControllerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _randomUserService:UserdataService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._randomUserService.getUserData().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data.name);//Try to print the name of the user as example

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the user as a result from the API, you get a more complex object and you need to fetch the user from that one. So in the service map to the results property of the response:

```
return this._http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=name,location,nat,picture')
    .map(res => res.json().results[0]);
```